# Excel with VBA - XmlHttp to use div

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel with VBA to open a page and extract some information and putting it in my database. After some research, I figured out that opening IE obviously takes more time and it can be achieved using XmlHTTP. I am using the XmlHTTP to open a web page as proposed in my another  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739552/excel-vba-to-open-the-first-search-result-page-of-google). However, while using IE I was able to navigate through div tags. How can I accomplish the same in XmlHTTP?

If I use IE to open the page, I am doing something like below to navigate through multiple div elements.

```
Set openedpage1 = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-experience").getElementsbyClassName("title")
For Each div In openedpage1
---------
```

However, with XmlHttp, I am not able to do like below.

```
For Each div In html.getElementById("profile-experience").getElementsbyClassName("title")
```

I am getting an error as **object doesn't support this property or method**.

Comment: You should show your current code.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9995257/53614) might be useful

Comment: @Ramesh If you can share the link i will try out that.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157849/extract-data-from-a-website-using-vba/17187924#17187924

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221427/1698517) that I had posted for another question as this is close to what you're looking for. In summary, you will:

1. Create a `Microsoft.xmlHTTP` object
2. Use the xmlHTTP object to open your url
3. Load the response as XML into a `DOMDOcument` object

From there you can get a set of `XMLNodes`, select elements, attributes, etc. from the `DOMDocument`

Comment: Isn't this way of creating the DOMDocument based on XML? Will it work for HTML? I don't think it will - I may be wrong. I think you would have to first save the HTML, and re-parse it.

Comment: Use a validator like the W3C one [here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri) to check if the page is well-formed XHTML before trying to import into a `DOMDocument`. If it isn't well-formed then you'll need a different approach altogether

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttp object returns the contents of the page as a string in `responseText`. You will need to parse this string to find the information you need. Regex is an option but it will be quite cumbersome.

[This page](http://www.vba-and-excel.com/vba/internet/6-loading-information-from-the-internet-using-the-xmlhttp-object) uses string functions (Mid, InStr) to extract information from the html-text.

It may be possible to create a DOMDocument from the retreived HTML (I believe it is) but I haven't pursued this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned with the answers above put the `.responseText` into an HTMLDocument and then work with that object e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.someurl.com", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim aNodeList As Object, iItem As Long
    Set aNodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#profile-experience.title")
    With ActiveSheet
        For iItem = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
            .Cells(iItem + 1, 1) = aNodeList.item(iItem).innerText
            '.Cells(iItem + 1, 1) = aNodeList(iItem).innerText '<== or potentially this syntax
        Next iItem
    End With
End Sub
```

Note:

I have literally translated your `getElementById("profile-experience").getElementsbyClassName("title")` into a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), `querySelectorAll("#profile-experience.title")`,  so assume that you have done that correctly.

Comment: Did you try this please?